# URLConnection connected getter

Tags: java, urlconnection

I was checking the documentation of the [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#Field_Summary) class and i wasn't able to find a getter/setter for the  *connected* field . While there is **getDoInput()** , there is no **isConnected()**. So i was wondering if there's a method or another way to check this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call `connect()` if there is already a connection nothing happens.

See the documentation of the `connect` method:

> If the connect method is called when the connection has already been
>   opened (indicated by the connected field having the value true), the
>   call is ignored.